# How to build a cron docker image properly?

Tags: cron, docker

I am trying to build a Debian-based image to dockerize a cron process, but my cron jobs are never started.
Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends cron
COPY jobs.txt /etc/crontab
RUN touch /log.txt
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

...and the `jobs.txt` file:

```
* * * * * root echo "job done" >> /log.txt
```

I realized that there is something wrong with the `COPY` command, because when I replace

```
COPY jobs.txt /etc/crontab
```

with

```
RUN echo '* * * * * root echo "job done" >> /log.txt' > /etc/crontab
```

it works perfectly.

So is there a problem just with `jobs.txt` file and Docker unable to copy it the right way? Should I only fix that file, or use a completely  different approach?

Comment: Maybe try to add empty line at and of jobs.txt.

Comment: @jazgot Yes, empty line at the end is a must, but yet it doesn't solve a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between using `COPY` and `RUN` are the permissions on the `/etc/crontab` file: with `COPY` this is 664 and with `RUN` 644.

I cannot find anything on permissions that `/etc/crontab` needs to have but if you add

```
RUN chmod 644 /etc/crontab
```

after the `COPY` line in your `Dockerfile` the cronjobs run (at least for me).
So I think the permissions have to be `644`

Comment: It's because of the linking that happens in the overlay filesystem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962020/cron-and-crontab-files-not-executed-in-docker/38850273#38850273

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every documented solution to this problem, and there is only one that works:

`cat /etc/crontab | crontab -`

If you already have some entries, you don't want to overwrite them.  In that case, do something like this:

`(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; cat /etc/crontab ) | crontab -`